# MongoDB update arrays entry

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document to Mongodb update array of objects like this:

```json
    {
    "myArray": [
            {
              "Key1": "string",
              "key2": {
                "entry": "aaa"
              }
            },
            {
              "Key1": "string",
              "key2": {
                "entry": "bbb"
              }
            }
          ]
    }
```

And I want to modify the key2 field in each object of myArray. The expected result should be :

```json
    {
    "myArray": [
            {
              "Key1": "string",
              "key2Modified":"aaa"
            },
            {
              "Key1": "string",
              "key2Modified":"bbb"
            }
          ]
    }
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Check out the [array update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/#array-update-operators) and arrayFilters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$map` in `$set`

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "myArray": {
        $map: {
          input: "$myArray",
          as: "a",
          in: {
            Key1: "$$a.Key1",
            key2Modified: "$$a.key2.entry"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TJZAya6fhXn)